# How to get the show text on current screen in iOS webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, webview

I want to add bookmark on the iOS UIWebView.
webview is loaded html document.
bookmark data should be the  text content position on current displaying screen in webview.
If it is possible , please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried, show us your code so we have a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: He hasnt tried anything, but got what he came for.. Just code.. Lazy developers will fall..

Answer (score 0):

With the UIWebView you get delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

So you gonna check the URL from `webViewDidFinishLoad` like so:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *requestUrlString = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"requestUrlString : %@", requestUrlString);
}
```

Then you can open and save the URL as a bookmark with CoreData or NSUserDefaults like this:

```
// New bookmark
NSDictionary *bookmark = @{@"bookmark_title":@"My Bookmark",  @"bookmark_url":@"https://www.google.com/"};

// Get bookmarks
NSMutableArray *bookmarks = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myBookmarks"];

// Update bookmarks
[bookmarks addObject: bookmark];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:bookmarks forKey:@"myBookmarks"]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```